# how to add interstitial ad to webview?

Tags: android, eclipse, webview, admob, interstitial

I just want interstitial ad in my main activity anyhow

```
    private void initAdmob() {
        if (isAdmobEnable) {
            adView = new AdView(this);
            adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
            adView.setAdUnitId(MY_AD_UNIT_ID);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        //  p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, webviewProgress.getId());
             p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            parentView.addView(adView, p);

            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

            // Start loading the ad in the background.
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the xml where you create the adView?

Comment: Don't do this, if you want copy the full source to [pasteofcode](http://paste.ofcode.org/)

Comment: is i have to create the adview of interstitial ad

Comment: Post your xml file please

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/Y6WNMc2grpqqRT555Z5aCZ

Comment: here my xml file 
http://paste.ofcode.org/nb4GmCHJPS2yt3B6xHhtKU

Answer (score 0):

Well since your code is extremely large I'll put a scenario to how to do it and you can guide with my code.

**1.** First of all make sure you have the code of `Google as services` in your `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
```

**2.** Add those lines on your `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

**3.** On your `Activity` where you want to add the `ad view` should contains this code :

```
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.ad_unit_id));
if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
} 
else {
       if (!mInterstitialAd.isLoaded() && !mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
       }  
}
```

If you want to add it programmatically you should include your `WebView` on a `LinearLayout` (easier) and then add it doing this :

```
private AdView adView;
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.INTERSTITIAL, getString(R.string.ad_unit_id));
LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_main_LinearLayout);
root.addView(adView);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

And if you don't want to do it programmatically just add the `AdView` on your `xml` file below the `WebView`

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="INTERSTITIAL"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">   
 </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: ad_unit_id cannot be resolved or is not a field
  i created a private string for interstial of ad_unit_id

Comment: Use `MY_AD_UNIT_ID`

Comment: MY_AD_UNIT_ID is used for banner ads

Comment: i added adview in my xml it says required attribute was missing.

Comment: i added mInterstitialAd; in my mainactivity where i want to show interstitial ad .program runs well but it does not load any ad. please help bro

Comment: Do you have internet conection?

Answer (score 0):

**import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;**

```
private InterstitialAd interstitial;





     interstitial = new InterstitialAd(WebViewActivity.this);
                // Insert the Ad Unit ID
                interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-6466988621230720/20102112499");


    // Request for Ads
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()

    // Add a test device to show Test Ads
    // .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    // .addTestDevice("0A8B6312AD2047B3E0951BFB32026553")
            .build();

    // Load ads into Banner Ads
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

    // Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // Call displayInterstitial() function
            displayInterstitial();
        }
    });
}
public void displayInterstitial() {
    // If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
        interstitial.show();
    }
}
```